# Looking for a book or movie about UFOs coming from a civilization living beneath the sea floor

Tags: story-identification, underground-civilization, ufos

Can anyone identify a story about a submarine crew who wind up finding a civilization living beneath the sea floor? This civilization is a peaceful race who visit the surface in UFOs to observe. Their culture is so honest and open crimes do not take place, like a better Singapore.

It is not The Abyss and I really don't remember if it was a book I read years ago or a movie.

Comment: Short story or novel? Approximately when did you read it? Do you know if it was new at the time?

Comment: I am confused by your statement "They also do not know of crimes or murder.", if the they are visiting our surface in UFO's how is it they are not aware (know of) crimes or murder?

Comment: They do visit but to observe. The better description would be that their culture is so honest and open crimes do not take place. Like a better Singapore.

Comment: It is not The Abyss and I really don't remember if it was a book I read years ago or a movie. It seems more a dream.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about Orson Scott Card's novelization of "[The Abyss](http://www.hatrack.com/osc/books/abyss.shtml)" ?

Answer (score 2):

Or perhaps you're thinking of the movie "[The Abyss](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096754/)", which is based on Card's work?

Comment: Cards novel is based on Camerons screenplay (OSC was hired to do the novelization), not the other way round.